# How to assign one value to a specific matrix entry, where the matrix must be called with a variable name

Tags: r, assign

I have the following problem: I have a huge list of matrices with unique names that share the same dimension. I calculate some values that I now want to assign to a certain matrix indice, e.g. [3,4]. Because I have so many matrices I created a list with the names that those matrices shall have and then I used `assign()` to create all those matrices (empty). I would now like to call single matrices with its variable name to assign different values to certain matrix entries. I only know the commands `assign() and eval(parse())`, but didn't manage to get it working. I tried several things without success:

`assign(x=MatrixNameList[i][3,4],value=z)`

`assign(x=MatrixNameList[i],value=z)[3,4]`

`eval(parse(text=MatrixNameList[i]))[3,4]<-z`

`assign(x=eval(parse(text=MatrixNameList[i]))[3,4] ,value=z)`

So I am wondering if there is a possibility for what I want to do. The structure of my code is a simple loop:

```
Matrix1 <- Matrix2 <- matrix(nrow=3,ncol=4)
MatrixNameList <- c('Matrix1', 'Matrix2')
for (i in 1:length(MatrixNameList)){
z <- calculatedValue <- 4 # different for the single matrices
assign... ?
eval(parse... ?
}
```

I hope I was able to clearly point out my problem. Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: If you went to the trouble to put the names of your matrices in a list, you should just put the matrices themselves in a list (which you really should have done in the first place). Then your task would be trivial.

Comment: You don't have a huge list of matrices.  If you had a huge list of matrices, `lapply(matlist, function(m) {m[3,4] <- z; m})` would be the solution.

Comment: @joran: I create the matrix names with paste(); I assumed that once the object gets very big (assume matrix of 10000*10000), it would be better to have many separate ones instead of one that is xxx times the size of the already big one. But I guess it doesn't matter.
Thanks for reply.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: matlist is the list object, but is there a way with get() or assign() to 'call' the variable from a list with strings? Just curious. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get`:

```
get(MatrixNameList[1])  # retrieves matrix called "Matrix1"
```

However, you're better off collecting all those matrices into one object. Something like this should get you started.

```
Matrices <- lapply(MatrixNameList, get)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign values like the following:

```
MatrixList <- list(Matrix1, Matrix2)
names(MatrixList) <- MatrixNameList

MatrixList[[1]][2,3] <- 4
# OR:
MatrixList$Matrix1[2,3] <- 4
```